# How to get new Search Engine results in the past 24h using a SERP API?

Tags: api, search

Assume I am in possession of a SERP API, which given a keyword, returns me the Google results of that keyword in JSON format (for example: https://serpapi.com/):

```json
{
"organic_results": [
  {

    "position": 1,
    "title": "Coffee - Wikipedia",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee",
    "displayed_link": "https://en.wikipedia.org › wiki › Coffee",
    "snippet": "Coffee is a brewed drink prepared from roasted coffee beans, the seeds of berries from certain Coffea species. From the coffee fruit, the seeds are ...",
    "sitelinks":{/*snip*/}
    ,
    "rich_snippet":
    {
        "bottom":
        {
            "extensions":
            [
                "Region of origin: Horn of Africa and ‎South Ara...‎",
                "Color: Black, dark brown, light brown, beige",
                "Introduced: 15th century"
            ]
            ,
            "detected_extensions":
            {
                "introduced_th_century": 15
            }
        }
    }
    ,
    "about_this_result":
    {
        "source":
        {
            "description": "Wikipedia is a free content, multilingual online encyclopedia written and maintained by a community of volunteers through a model of open collaboration, using a wiki-based editing system. Individual contributors, also called editors, are known as Wikipedians.",
            "source_info_link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia",
            "security": "secure",
            "icon": "https://serpapi.com/searches/6165916694c6c7025deef5ab/images/ed8bda76b255c4dc4634911fb134de53068293b1c92f91967eef45285098b61516f2cf8b6f353fb18774013a1039b1fb.png"
        }
        ,
        "keywords":
        [
            "coffee"
        ]
        ,
        "languages":
        [
            "English"
        ]
        ,
        "regions":
        [
            "the United States"
        ]
    }
    ,
    "cached_page_link": "https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:U6oJMnF-eeUJ:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee+&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us",
    "related_pages_link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=related:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee+Coffee"
  },
/* Results 2,3,4... */
]}
```

What is a good way to get new results from the past 24h? I added the [`&tbs=qdr:d` query parameter](https://support.google.com/websearch/thread/16003605/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-default-google-search-timeframe-for-example-default-to-past-year?hl=en&msgid=16027482), which only shows the results from the past day. That's a good first step.

The 2nd step is to filter out only relevant results. When there are no relevant results, Google shows this message box:

[image: google message box]

What is their algorithm to show this box?

### Idea 1: "grep -i {exact_keywords}"

For example, if I search a keyword like "Alexander Pope", the 24h Google query might return results about the pope, written by a guy called Alexander. That's not super relevant. My naive idea is to grep (case insensitive) the exact keyword "Alexander Pope".

But that might leave out some good results.

Any other ideas?